# How do I write this mathematical equation?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

I want to write the shown mathematical equation in LaTeX but I am getting an error. Here this is not eta but it is `n`. The code which I am writing is

```
\begin{equation}
\Delta {E} +  \frac{\omega^2 n$_{i}$^2}{c^2} E = 0
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: What are the dollar signs for? You cannot use them within the equation environment. Without them, it works.

Comment: `\omega^{2} n_{i}^{2}` will do.

Comment: Moreover, it's not `n` but `\eta`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code incorrectly contains dollar signs, which are not allowed directly in a math display:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Suppose \( E \) satisfies the following differential equation
\begin{equation}
  \Delta E + \frac{\omega^2 \eta_i^2}{c^2} E = 0.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The curly brackets `{...}` around the first `E` are unnecessary.  On the other hand you might consider writing brackets around super- and subscripts:

```
\omega^{2} \eta_{i}^{2}
```

so you don't get surprised when you have more complicated material in these positions.